# Unable to update Windows 10 programatically

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-10

Would like to apply the Windows 10 November upgrade programatically to my Windows 10 Pro machines. Since this is to be done on a large number of machines, it has to be done programatically.

For this have used the following script to execute the upgrade - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387102(VS.85).aspx

Output:

```
Installation Result: 3
Reboot Required: True
Listing of updates installed and individual installation results:
1> Update for Windows 10 for x64-based Systems (KB3106932): 2
2> Upgrade to Windows 10 Pro, version 1511, 10586: 4
3> Cumulative Update for Windows 10 for x64-based Systems (KB3116869): 2
4> Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows 8, 8.1, 10 and Windows Server 2012, 2012 R2 x64 Edition - December 2015 (KB890830): 2
5> Definition Update for Windows Defender - KB2267602 (Definition 1.213.77.0): 2
```

The installation result code `4` for Windows 10, version 1511 means that it failed. So I ran a `shutdown /r /t 1` and the ran the script again.

Second Output:

```
Installation Result: 2
Reboot Required: True
Listing of updates installed and individual installation results:
1> Upgrade to Windows 10 Pro, version 1511, 10586: 2
The installation result code 2 means that it was successful.
```

I ran a reboot but the Windows 10 Pro wasn't updated.

Can anyone tell what I am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks, thanks for your time. Have tried deleting files in `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download` and running the script again, but to no avail.

Finally, unzipped the `.iso` file and executed the `setup.exe` using the `/quiet /noreboot /unattend <path to answer file>` switches.

Now, deploy across many machines can be automated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried using the script you are using to do Windows updates automatically. Previously (back when I had a job that required me to do things like that), I used the WSUS offline tool available [here](http://download.wsusoffline.net/). That works like a charm for Windows 7 and others (haven't tried with Windows 10 but I imagine it will be fine). Basically, the tool lets you download all updates available for the OSes it supports. It then generates an update script that can be run on all the machines you want. It is community supported and there are quite a few people that submit fixes and improvements, making it a very solid tool.

I don't know if you are able to change tracks at this point and try out this tool but I can definitely recommend it for tasks like the one you are trying to accomplish.

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the actual update is causing issues for you.

Assuming that the script works good for you(which it seems like it does since the other updates applied) I would look at trying to purge the download. See the following link for more info:

https://superuser.com/questions/1000529/upgrade-to-windows-10-pro-version-1511-10586-errors-with-0x8024200d